# SHA256 of a binary string?

Tags: hash, sha256

I have a JSON object and I need to calculate the SHA256 hash of it. Now, I can either serialize it into a binary string or a human readable string.

My question is does calculating the SHA256 hash of a binary string make any sence or should I go the human readable string route?

Comment: SHA256 operates on bytes.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm does not care about that. Eventually it will take the bits of what you provided and calculates the hash.

If you want to compare hashes, you obviously just need to make sure that you doing it the same way.

When it comes to speed, I tend to say that the binary string will be faster. Human readable representations have often far more indentations and in general "overhead", which means more bits to process.